# error message after spatstat::Gcross function: Error in marks.ppp(X, ...) : Sorry, not implemented when the marks are a data frame

Tags: r, spatstat, r-ppp

I read a shapefile using **maptools** package and then converted to `.ppp`

```
hfmd <- readShapeSpatial("NEWMERGE.shp")
hfmd2 <- as(hfmd, 'ppp')
```

When I typed `hfmd2`, I received this

```
Marked planar point pattern: 1092 points`
Mark variables: X, Y, Status, ID` 
window: rectangle = [492623.7, 609905.3] x [444011.4, 645190.4] units`
```

And when I typed `Gcross(hfmd2)` to run **Cross G** function, I received this error

```
Error in marks.ppp(X, ...) :` 
Sorry, not implemented when the marks are a data frame`
```

My questions are:

1. Does `Gcross()` only work with Multitype Marked planar point pattern object?
2. How do I convert a `.ppp` object to a Multitype Marked planar point pattern object?

Answer (score 0):

Your current `ppp` has four different mark values: `X`, `Y`, `Status`, `ID`. Which one do you want to use for `Gcross`? For now I will assume it is `Status`. Then you can replace the `data.frame` containing the four mark values for each point with a single mark vector like this:

```
marks(hfmd2) <- marks(hfmd2)$Status
```

Now you should be able to run `Gcross`:

```
Gc <- Gcross(hfmd2)
```

This will estimate `Gcross` between the first two types in `Status`.

Comment: Or `subset(hfmd2, select='Status')`